# Trouble with alternating text color in MyBB

Tags: javascript, mybb

I'm trying to alternate text color for my usergroup titles and having a bit of trouble. I was using this, but it wasn't properly working for some reason. It'd only show up in one spot and nowhere else would it work properly, and it also cut off the last letter of their usernames.

This is the javascript:

```
    window.onload=function(){
var HTML = '';

function alternate(colorpair) {
    var el = document.getElementById('alternator');
    if (!HTML) HTML = el.innerHTML;
    var text = HTML.match(/\S\s*(?=\S)/g), output = '';
    for (var w=0; w<text.length; w++) {
        output += '<span style="color:' + ((w%2) ? colorpair[0] : colorpair[1]);
        output += ';">' + text[w] + '</span>';
    }
    console.log(output);
    el.innerHTML = output;
}
alternate(['green', 'purple']);
```

and this is the usergroup markup

```
<span id="alternator" class="none">{username}.</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using an `id`, but IDs must be unique within the document.  Use a class and `getElementsByClassName`.  (You don't try to loop over elements anywhere, so why would this run more than once?)

It cuts the last letter off because of your regex: `(?=\S)` means "there must be some non-whitespace next", so there will always be a letter *outside* the regex, and you only preserve the bit the regex matches.

I'm confused about the use of the outer `var HTML`; that's not necessary and will probably corrupt titles after the first one.

Lastly, not that I'm a designer or anything, but I'm pretty sure alternating green and purple letters will look *terrible*.  :)

Comment: Yeah it doesn't look good, it's just a test. I found the code from somebody else asking for similar help on here, and that's the colors they were using. It still isn't working so I'm just giving up for now.

Comment: Care to share the code you have found that works?  It helps the rest of the community out who are having the same issue.